# install4j update information download from cloud failure

Tags: install4j

I test the auto-update feature of trial install4j 7.0.8 (Windows 10 Home).

When I put update information to Amazon S3 bucket, I get popup message "The update information could not be downloaded from https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/bucket/../updates.xml Please check your network connection." 
We use Amazon S3 a lot and this is a first time that client can't download from Amazon S3.

When I put update information to our Tomcat server and change url in updater to http://.../updates.xml, everything is ok.

Why Install4J can't download from cloud service?

Thank you.

Mikhail.

Comment: Is there any more information in the log file? For update checkers you can pass `-Dinstall4j.keepLog` as a parameter to keep the log file in the %TEMP% directory.

Comment: @Ingo Kegel I don't know why but the download issue was solved after I enabled access logging on S3 and than disabled it, because logging generated too many files with message "Access denied" for unknown to me reason. And install4j updater now is able to download update.xml from S3. 
Thank you.